# How to Kill Google Chrome Process Suspended (Access Denied)

Tags: google-chrome, process, kill

Often (at least 3 times a day) my google chrome gets suspended on the task manager and there is nothing I can do to kill the process but to restart the system. And restarting my computer is so much is annoying with so much work opened.
I already tried using `TASKKILL /F /IM "chrome.exe"` but it doesn't kill, I get the Acess Denied message. I tried with different prompts (cmd, powershell, hyper).
Can someone see a solution for that?

[chrome suspended on task manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VizQr.png)

Comment: What about Process Hacker?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that Google wont fix for years. So what I did was to install Process Hacker and whenever Chrome crashes I go to Process Hacker and terminate just the chrome suspended (dark color) process. Doing that you wont lose any open tab.

https://processhacker.sourceforge.io/